# RangeError when playing audio through opusscript

Tags: node.js, electron, discord.js, opus

I've been attempting to use electron to play sounds through a discord bot. However, I've come across three issues with this.

The first is that the code I'd usually use to play a sound file though discord returns an error stating that I am lacking opus.node and opusscript. This shouldn't be happening, as I have @discordjs/opus installed, and running this same code outside of the electron instance works perfectly fine.

```js
message.member.voice.channel.join().then((connection) => {
    const dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlAU_w7-Xp8", { quality: "highestaudio" }));
    dispatcher.on("finish", () => {
        console.log("Song is finished.");
    });
});
```

To get around the error, I installed opusscript. However, this is where the second issue comes in. I am able to run the sound - for the first 9 times. After the ninth time, the bot emits the following error:

```
(node:21064) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: offset is out of bounds
at Uint16Array.set (<anonymous>)
at OpusScript.encode (C:\Users\spiralio\Desktop\sb\node_modules\opusscript\index.js:67:16)
at Encoder._encode (C:\Users\spiralio\Desktop\sb\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\Opus.js:60:25)
at Encoder._transform (C:\Users\spiralio\Desktop\sb\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\Opus.js:157:30)
at Encoder.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:191:10)
at Encoder.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:179:12)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
at Encoder.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
at VolumeTransformer.ondata (_stream_readable.js:716:22)
```

This error only occurs if the sound file I'm playing overlaps onto itself 9 times. If I let it finish before this error plays, I can continue playing sounds just fine. However, once the error plays, no matter how long I wait sound no longer plays.

A solution I tried was to have the bot run in the renderer process instead of the main process. However, this prompts me with the issue that the bot can't connect to a voice channel from a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a few issues at play here.

Firstly, the root issue here is that we're encoding a file that's too large. I suspect that the videos are snowballing to such a point where we hit a brick wall.

I'd try downloading only the audio to avoid sending files too large (see [ytdl options](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core#ytdlchooseformatformats-options)).

```js
message.member.voice.channel.join().then((connection) => {
    const dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlAU_w7-Xp8", { quality: "highestaudio", filter: "audioonly" }));
    dispatcher.on("finish", () => {
        console.log("Song is finished.");
    });
});
```

Electron not detecting [`@discordjs/opus`](https://npmjs.com/@discordjs/opus) seems to be a deeper issue with native modules and your builder. Are you experiencing this in production, or do you have a recreation of your Electron setup somewhere?

Comment: I've "solved" the issue by switching to a web app. However, I'll mark this as the answer an answer any questions for anyone watching.  

"I'd try downloading only the audio to avoid sending files too large"
The issue also persists if the audio is a file, no matter of the size.

"Are you experiencing this in production, or do you have a recreation of your Electron setup somewhere?"
This snippet of code is a recreation of the issue in a smaller test environment, where the issue is also there (if that's what you mean)